Как подключить телефон к Docker через ADB?
У меня есть контейнер Docker, и к этому компьютеру подключён телефон. Когда я выполняю команду adb devices на компьютере, телефон отображается в списке устройств. Однако если я выполню эту команду внутри контейнера Docker, телефон уже не будет отображаться. Как можно решить эту проблему?
Мой Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-bookworm
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y adb
ports: - "5037:5037"
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python","-u", "main.py"]

